# How can a variable be deallocated after it is dropped?

Tags: rust

I'm reading through ["learn rust with entirely too many linked lists"](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-drop.html) .
In chapter 2.7 the author says that "*We can't drop the contents of the Box after deallocating"*. How can a value be deallocated after it is dropped? Wouldn't the deallocation occur in the implementation of drop or are these separate concepts?

For some context, the author is explaining why the particular implementation of a linked list is not tail recursive and thus cannot be optimised by the compiler.

Linked List:

```
pub struct List {
    head: Link,
}

enum Link {
    Empty,
    More(Box<Node>),
}

struct Node {
    elem: i32,
    next: Link,
}
```

Drop implementation :

```
impl Drop for List {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // NOTE: you can't actually explicitly call `drop` in real Rust code;
        // we're pretending to be the compiler!
        self.head.drop(); // tail recursive - good!
    }
}

impl Drop for Link {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        match *self {
            Link::Empty => {} // Done!
            Link::More(ref mut boxed_node) => {
                boxed_node.drop(); // tail recursive - good!
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Box<Node> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.ptr.drop(); // uh oh, not tail recursive!
        deallocate(self.ptr);
    }
}

impl Drop for Node {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.next.drop();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are confused by the phrase "the contents of". You can't drop *the contents of* a `Box<Node>` before deallocating it, i.e. you can't drop the `Node` *and then* deallocate the `Box`. The deallocation is part of the `Drop` implementation for *the `Box` itself*, not its contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wouldn't the deallocation occur in the implementation of drop or are these separate concepts?

They're separate concepts. In the example code, `Drop` means "clean up my *contents*/*owned resources*", `deallocate` means "return the memory I was actually stored in to the pool".

The `drop` method is run with a reference to the existing instance. [The definition of `drop` actually says](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html#tymethod.drop):

> When this method has been called, `self` has not yet been deallocated. That only happens after the method is over. If this wasn’t the case, `self` would be a dangling reference.

As a result, the `head` *must* be fully dropped before it can be deallocated. And the dropping process requires dropping all the nodes in the list first, each of which will deallocate the associated node only after the drop finishes, leading to a stack of `drop`s, each of which *will* be followed by a `deallocate`, but only after all the `drop`s and `deallocates` above them on the stack complete. Since you can't perform a single `deallocate` until `drop` has been called along the entire stack (at which point the `drop` for the tail node returns and the tail node is the first deallocated), it can't be implemented tail-recursively.

---

Side-note: This is the exact same problem you see in C++ trying to implement a linked list using `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` for the `next` pointer. Just like Rust, C++ distinguishes destruction (cleaning resources *within* the object) from deallocations (releasing the memory that *held* the object). When the `head` `unique_ptr` is cleared, before it can release the memory it has to tell "`head` + 1" to clear its own `unique_ptr`, which in turn tells the "`head` + 2" to clear its `unique_ptr` and so on. In every case, destruction (via the destructor) must precede deallocation (which might occur via `operator delete` for heap allocated stuff, or just by the compiler contracting the stack without actually releasing any memory for stack allocated stuff).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with tail-recursion on `impl Drop for Box<Node>` is that we have to `self.ptr.drop()` and *then* `deallocate(self.ptr)`; tail-recursion would require us to `deallocate(self.ptr)` and *then* `self.ptr.drop()` (so `drop()` recurses in the function's tail position).

The problem is that when we `deallocate(self.ptr)` first, the content of `self.ptr` is immediately in an undefined state because it's deallocated memory. If we then `self.ptr.drop()`, we would need a `&mut Box<Node>` to do the `drop()` call (where this shows up as `&mut self`).

Not only would this mean that the destructor effectively accesses memory that has been deallocated. It also means that we have to create a `reference` in the form of a `&mut Box<Node>` that points to memory that is in an undefined state. In Rust, this would be **Undefined Behavior**, as Rust gives *very* strict guarantees about the memory a `reference` points to.